# how to access to physical address on VXworks in C/c++?

Tags: arm, vxworks

I am trying to read FPGA (altera cyclone IV) registers from ARM cortex A8 ona board with Vxworks 6.9.

for example

```
   #define My_FPGA_IP_Address_Base 0x00000400
   #define mm_avalon 0x25000000

   int main(){
   vxWorks_read_fromAddr (mm_avalon + My_FPGA_IP_Address_Base) ; //how can I get this on Vxworks
   }
```

Could anyone help me out, thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I access my memory mapped I/O Device (FPGA) from a RTP in VxWorks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113001/how-do-i-access-my-memory-mapped-i-o-device-fpga-from-a-rtp-in-vxworks)

Comment: The correct way to do this is to interface through a device driver in the kernel. By design you shouldn't access memory mapped IO from the RTP

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the register using a normal pointer with a virtual address.

`int* myRegister = mm_avalon + My_FPGA_IP_Address_Base + registerOffset;
int myRegisterValue = *myRegister;`

or

`*myRegister = 10;`

Assuming your register is write enable.

Look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157019/vxworks-6-8-mapping-physical-to-virtual-memory) which seems related for more info.

Comment: thanks for ur anwser, but with which Vxworks API can I access in reading from the hardware ?

Comment: You don't need any system call or special function, you just access the register like a global memory location in your program.

Comment: Sorry It didn't work,    int* myregister = (int*) 0x25000400 ; then I did a simple printf: I got an error: "RTP 0x824abfd8 has been deleted due to signal 11."; Are you sure that we can read from physical address by using a simple c-pointer ?

Comment: I would advice not to use RTP to access it, use it as part of  driver which resides on kernel image (VIP). I agree to Nomios, you should be able to access the memory using pointers, no special API us required.

Comment: @sam60 the error you got was most probably causes by accessing a wrong address. can you check the content of this address using a terminal on your target? You also may have a support package remapping your addresses.